# How could I feed a custom image into this model?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, mnist

I've been following a course online and one of the exercises was to create a simple image detection model (using MNIST data) to detect written numbers. I've been trying to load a custom image I drew in (128x128 jpg) but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm really close, but I think I'm just confused about what parameters the model takes in. Any help would be appreciated!!

[Here is my code](https://gist.github.com/diericx/261391cebbbe5970e266a4ebbdc09bc6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert your image to an `128x128` numpy array with values between 0 and 1.

Then:

```
image = Variable(torch.from_numpy(image))[None, :, :]
classification = model(image)
```

`classification` is then a pytorch Variable containing probabilities of belonging to each class.

Comment: Okay, here's how I'm feeding in the data in (I make it a 1x1x28x28 because I think the model is trying to take in a bunch of images)
[link to gist](https://gist.github.com/diericx/01de2f1a4874e994957523857c9713c2) but the data is all wrong, almost random. Does it look like I'm doing some conversions wrong somewhere?

Comment: Is your model fully connected or convolutional? If it is convolutional (as one would expect) you shouldn't flatten the data: `data = np.array( img, dtype='float' ).flatten()`. Normally MNIST doesn't have a channel dim because it has no colour so typically what you feed in to your network is of shape `MBx28x28`

Comment: Right. I just looked at your code again. Indeed you are using a fully connected network. Thus what you do in your gist is correct.

Comment: Do you know why I would be getting random results? I printed out the data I'm putting in and it looks exactly the same as the test data. Not sure what could be throwing it off :(

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "random results". You need to explain better what the problem is. For example maybe your model overfitted to your training data and it only works for the training data and nothing else. Do you have a validation set? How does your validation loss look like?

Comment: In any case. There is nothing wrong with how you are feeding the data, so you should ask a new question for that. And give examples of what exactly goes wrong.